# What can I do? My employer told a coworker that I complained about her

Tags: colleagues

There is a coworker that will come in when she feels like it. She was 50 minutes late on Tuesday. My boss called and asked if we would like to go to a meeting with him. I told him as soon as she arrived I would let him know. He told me whenever she gets there, please just come to the meeting. I did. He wrote her up (this is not the first time she has been late) and told her that I was "bitching" about her being late. I only answered the questions he asked. What I can do? I do not feel safe in my job at all anymore.

Comment: I think you'd want to trace back the source of the "bitching" comment.  There are those who honestly believe that when they do something wrong, the person who notices it is the one at fault.  Sounds like you may have one of those on your hands.  I'd bet the actual convo was more like "Bethany said you weren't in, yet."

Comment: Did you hear your boss tell her you were bitching about her or did she tell you he said that?  I'd wager she drew conclusions and made assumptions.  I doubt you have anything to worry about from your boss... though I would distance my self personally from your coworker who does sound like she is on her way out.

Answer (score 3):

A direct conversation with her to clarify your role in the whole drama might go a long way to fixing things with her.

As for fixing your broken trust in your boss that is an entirely different can of worms.  Ideally you have a private discussion of what specifically was done (eg pulling you into the middle of something), how it negatively effects you (eg your trust in him diminished and your relationship with her tarnished), and what can be done to fix the situation(eg never happen again and he clarifies to co-worker that you were only answering direct questions).  In my experience those who are willing to flat out lie about you do not care how their actions effect you so this conversation may have very little positive impact.

Answer (score -2):

You simply go to your co-worker and tell her: "In case you're wondering: I want to clarify that I never bitched about you."

Comment: If you tell me that, i will hear the total opposite in my mind.